# How to use position within the string to change each string in a Pandas Dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to remove the 3rd and 4th letter in every string in a column of a DF. It's a different letter each time, so I don't know how to use regex to do it.
For example, if my DF is:

```
{A                     B           C

'32435'                3           5

'45243'                2           4}
```

I'm trying to turn it into:

```
{A                     B           C

'325'                  3           2

'453'                  2           4}
```

Comment: Why did `C` in the first row become 2 instead of 5?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To help others answer your question better, consider including details explaining _what you have tried_ or _the research you have done_ and _why it hasn't worked_. You might want to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more information.

Comment: df['A'].apply(lambda a: a[:2] + a[4:]) should do the trick. Regex is not needed here. Have a look at Python slicing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-pythons-slice-notation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code for this:

```
DF["A"] = DF["A"].map(lambda x: str(x)[0:2]+str(x)[4])
```

This will give column A as:

```
"325"
"453"
```

This method is faster and more efficient than the other methods suggested.

Answer (score 1):

```
df['A']=df['A'].str[:2]+df['A'].str[-1]
```

Comment: I think it should be df['A'].str[4:] if there are more than 5 ciphers in a string. But I like that is completely vectorized (without apply).

Answer (score 0):

If column A is not guaranteed to be of length 5 it might be helpful to check for that first:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['32435','45243','123']})

def stripstring(s):
    # put in try except in case string is short
    try:
        return s[:2] + s[4:]
    except IndexError:
        return s

df['A'] = df.apply(lambda row: stripstring(row['A']), axis=1)
```

## output

```
    A
0  '325'
1  '453'
2   '12'
```